# Is it possible to check if the memory address allocated by a variable falls into range of heap?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, heap-memory, clr

In C#, is there a way to check whther the memory address allocated by CLR for a variable falls into the range of heap or stack?

Comment: Why could it possibly matter?

Comment: Context? Is this a `ref`/`out` parameter? Or a `struct` field? Or? In most other cases you can *reason* where it lives...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliveber : Just curiosity

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliveber : Actually, I was thinking if I have variable whic returns true for (vaariable.GetType() is System.ValueType) but the addrerss falls into heap, I can assume that it is a boxed value type

Comment: I was under the impression that variables in .NET were not guaranteed to stay at a specific memory address (by default anyway), so if that is true would your question still matter?

Comment: That sounds backwards - if you have a variable that *might* contain a boxed value type, it will necessarily be some form of reference. If, in turn, its type is a value type, then it *must* be a boxed value type. There's no way that this variable can *ever* contain an unboxed value type.

Comment: @Damien the **variable** is completely unrelated to the **object**. If it could be a "box", then it is a reference-type, so: it is on the heap: always. The *variable* could be anywhere.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliveber, your methodology wouldn't work - in addition to implicitly boxed value types, value types that are the property of reference types would also appear on the heap.  There's an Eric Lippert article [from a couple years ago that's linked from your Visual Studio home screen where he basically yells at people asking this question](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx). :-)  The difference between Value and Reference types in the .NET framework is primarily about passing semantics, not where they are stored.

Comment: @pencilCake, `variable.GetType() is System.ValueType` doesn't make any sense. `GetType()` always returns a `Type`, which is not a value type, so the expression is always `false`.

Comment: @MarcGravell, et al. I believe that the question is poorly phrased, especially based on the follow up on boxed vs unboxed values - I believe the OP is really talking about values, not variables (especially since variables may not *have* a memory location - they may have been allocated to a register)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) debugging extension. These two commands will display you *all* the content of the stack and heap:

```
!DumpStackObjects 
!DumpHeap
```

Although I am not really sure how to quickly find a particular variable in question. Those commands will output quite a lot variables to naviage through.

Comment: +1, beat me to it.  You can also use the -type switch on DumpHeap to dump objects of a given type, and you can use that to find instances of your struct.